# Firestore Get Started Write and Deploy Your First Function install error

Tags: node.js, windows, firebase-tools

When going through the [Cloud Functions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) docs and try to install npn. I get a bunch of errors when running this command from an Admin CMD window in Windows 10

> npm install -g firebase-tool

This is the CMD output please advice on what this means. Why when I run as Admin it say "Please try running this command again as root/Administrator."

Here´s the complete log:

> https://docs.google.com/document/d/19cO2iFSmYC7QkfcDg6BR5S4RgWkz-b6rq0aUmhLoEM0/edit?usp=sharing

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I installed [Nodejs 9.1.0](https://nodejs.org/en/) current version that was the problem. Now after uninstall and cleanup installing version [8.9.1 LTS recommended](https://nodejs.org/en/) solved the problem

The [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started) should really mention the version compatibility